# Default SSMS Settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssms, sql-server-2012-express

I just started an internship in which I'll be working with VB (decent experience), ASP (decent experience about 15 years ago), Dynamics NAV (never heard of it until now), SQL Server(some DB, but not setting it up) .  So, I downloaded Visual Studio Express and it automatically installed SQL Server 2012 Express because I wanted VB.  Now, I'm trying to use SS Management Studio the first time and I have no idea of what the server name is.  There are no options for a local connection and the only network connection is another computer.  I tried running

sqlcmd -S [SERVER] -d [DB_NAME] -E -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"

And that came up with a slew of errors.  [image]
I have never set up any kind of database before and I'm at a loss.  I don't even know if it is running at the moment.  I checked under Control Panel->Services and there is a SQLServer VSS Writer running, is that what I need?  Should I just uninstall it and try reinstalling? I appreciate your help, but I'm warning you now that I might have a lot of questions......

Comment: You don't appear to have started SSMS at all here. SSMS is a graphical IDE. Go to your start menu and type SSMS and launch it!

Comment: The problem is that when I try log into SQL Server, it is asking for information that I don't remember giving.  When I installed VB, it also installed SQL Server.  Then I had to download SSMS separately.  But, when I start SSMS,  It is asking for a server name, user name, and user password.  Things don't I don't even remember setting.